# Hide variables within an anonymous JavaScript function but access them using `this`

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

I'll use the following JavaScript code to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

```
var App = function() {

    var url
    var width
    var height

    function init()
    {
        url = window.location.href
        width = document.body.clientWidth
        height = document.body.clientHeight
    }

    function run()
    {
        init()
        alert(url + ' - ' + width + 'x' + height)
    }

    return {
        run: run
    }
}()

App.run()
```

( Run this code at: http://jsfiddle.net/zePq9/ )

The above code achieves three things:

1. Avoids global variables and functions (except the global object `App` which is intentionally exposed to the global namespace).
2. Hides the `url`, `width` and `height` variables and the `init()` function within the anonmyous function.
3. Exposes only the `run()` function outside the anonymous function.

However, I do not like this approach much because the `init()` and `run()` functions have to work with variables like `url`, `width` and `height`. In a more involved and larger JavaScript code, it is difficult to see the variable `url` in a function and tell where it is coming from. One has to do a lot of scrolling to answer questions like: Is it a local variable? Is it a global variable? Is it local only to the anonmyous function?

Right now I am solving this problem with the following code.

```
var App = function() {

    var self = {
        url: '',
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    }

    function init()
    {
        self.url = window.location.href
        self.width = document.body.clientWidth
        self.height = document.body.clientHeight
    }

    function run()
    {
        init()
        alert(self.url + ' - ' + self.width + 'x' + self.height)
    }

    return {
        run: run
    }
}()

App.run()
```

( Run this code at: http://jsfiddle.net/cXALf/ )

Now, I can clearly see `self.url` and tell that this variable is coming from the `self` object, the scope of which I know is limited to the anonmyous function due to my coding convention of using `self` object to hold together variables shared by all functions within an anonymous function. Note that `self.url` is still hidden within the anonymous function and is not visible outside it.

Ideally, I would like to use `this.url`, `this.width`, etc. instead of `self.url`, `self.width`, etc. But I am unable to arrive at a solution that would keep `this.url`, `this.width`, etc. invisible from outside the anonmyous function. Is it possible?

Comment: @YD1m My semicolon key works fine. I do not use semicolon while writing JavaScript code as my coding convention since it is not mandatory to use semicolon except in certain situations where new statements begin with `(`, `[`, etc.

Comment: It is possible but it I don't understand the point of creating truly private variable in a closure and referencing it via `this`.  IMO it is a problem that doesn't need solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to permanently set the `this` value of each function:

```
var App = function() {

    var self = {
        url: '',
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    };

    var init = function()
    {
        this.url = window.location.href;
        this.width = document.body.clientWidth;
        this.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    }.bind(self);

    var run = function()
    {
        init();
        alert(self.url + ' - ' + self.width + 'x' + self.height);
    }.bind(self);

    return {
        run: run
    }
}();
```

Note the older browser don't support bind, but you can [use a polyfill](https://www.google.com/#q=bind%20polyfill) to add it to browsers that don't supply it automatically.

Note that I don't necessarily think this code is a *good idea*, but it does do exactly what you want. I personally think there's nothing wrong with using `self` as an explicit container for your variables, and using `this` instead may make your code harder for others to understand (as they may assume `App` is meant to have instances).

Comment: I agree with your note that this code is probably not a good idea and sticking with `self` object is neater and simpler.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer since this solves my problem precisely as stated. However, I am not going to use this in my code due to reasons mentioned in my comment above this comment.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you consider to be *invisible* you can use one of several solutions. However, each solution has its own failings.

What you must consider is why you want to use the keyword `this` in relation to your "private variables". In JavaScript, there is not really a concept of private variables (more on this later). Anything that is accessible from one context is accessible from another.

### Bind to a closure-bound variable

This solution is closest to the solution you had originally, but using `Function.prototype.bind` to force the context to be a closure-internal object.

```
function App() {
  var self = {
    url: '',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  };

  var init = function() {
    this.url = window.location.href;
    this.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    this.height = document.body.clientHeight;
  }.bind(self);

  var run = function() {
    init();
    console.log(this.url + ' - ' + this.width + 'x' + this.height);
  }.bind(self);

  return {
    run: run
  };
}
```

The downfall of this approach is that every "member" function must be `.bind()` to `self`, or else the context of those functions will not be the closure-internal `self` that you have declared. This approach is also not very *Javascript-y*, due to having to create every method and property in what amounts to the constructor. This obviates the prototypal inheritance system that JavaScript has.

### Use ES5 property definitions

If you are willing to stick to only ES5-compliant JS engines (This mostly means no IE less than 9), you can use ES5's `Object.defineProperty()` to hide properties of an object. You will still be able to access them from other contexts, but at least they won't show up in enumerations of the object properties.

```
function App() {
  this.url = window.location.href;
  this.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  this.height = document.body.clientHeight;
}

Object.defineProperties(App.prototype, {
  url: {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: ""
  },
  width: {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: 0
  },
  height: {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: 0
  }
});

App.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log(this.url + ' - ' + this.width + 'x' + this.height);
};

new App().run();
```

The advantage to this technique is that you are able to exactly control which properties are enumerable ('visible' to enumeration like `for...in` or `Object.keys()`), and which ones are not. In addition, the construction of the `App` object takes place in its actual constructor, and the implementation of `run()` can now be overridden by child classes. The downside is that this requires an ES5 compatible engine, and that this does not prevent outside code from accessing or modifying `url`, `width`, or `height`, if they have access to the instance of `App`.

The only way to get true *privacy* in JavaScript is to declare variables inside a scope, and offer accessors that are also defined in the same scope. The scoping mechanism in JavaScript simply makes references to those variables impossible from outside the scope. Similarly, anonymous instances can do nearly the same thing... If you never use an instance of `App` beyond the only call to `run`, like:

```
new App().run();
```

Then the instance created by `new App()` will not be accessible anywhere else. This is not true privacy in that having reference to that instance still allows you access to all its properties, but it may be enough.

Answer (score -1):

Your app can be converted to something like this (it uses `this` and has no closures):

EDIT this solution ignores the hidden part, I skipped over the first part of the question.  IMO true variable hiding is not worth the effort and overhead in JS.  This code is leaner and has less overhead than others but no hiding.

```
function App() {
    this.init();
}

App.prototype = {
    url: '',
    width: 0,
    height: 0,

    init: function() {
        this.url = window.location.href
        this.width = document.body.clientWidth
        this.height = document.body.clientHeight
    },

    run: function() {
        console.log(this.url + ' - ' + this.width + 'x' + this.height)
    }
}

new App().run();
```

Comment: This solution doesn't hide `url`, `width`, etc. from being accessed from outside. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/nkCd3/

Comment: @LoneLearner I misunderstood the question.  I thought your problem stemmed from not understanding prototypical inheritance.  IMO making truly private variables is not worth the effort.

Comment: @LoneLearner you could prefix them with `_` to communicate internal field, no need to fight against the language